# Ajax.Actionlink not working with Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, actionlink

I realize this is an answer to my own issue but after reading [this link on the meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) I figured I would post this in hopes that it helps someone avoid spending hours trying to find an answer like I did.

I was trying to add an **Ajax.Actionlink** to a client template for MVC grid and was getting cryptic error 'Invalid template'. 
Finally found the issue to stem from the UpdateTargetID = "myElement".
**Ajax.ActionLink** generates an unescaped "#" for the update target which completely breaks the grid.

I do not have the monthly plan to post to Telerik forums regarding this issue otherwise I would have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My work around was:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Title("myTitle")
                            .ClientTemplate(Ajax.ActionLink("View", "myAction", "myController", new { myParam = "#=ID#" }, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "myJSFunction" }).ToHtmlString());
```

**Then:**

```
function myJSFunction(response) {
    $("#updateTargetElement").html(response);
}
```